# how to make the onreboot service work in a better way

Tags: android, service, location, reboot

I have a code that must work on reboot; It's a service that will recreate the alarms that I used to have before that the device shut down...

My code is :

```
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {        
         c=context;
        sp= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        sp.edit().putInt("CheckeForConnectionNumber", 0).commit();
        Toast.makeText(c,"checknumber= "+sp.getInt("CheckeForConnectionNumber", 

0), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    bool_activate_reminder=sp.getBoolean("reminder_on_off", false);

     if(bool_activate_reminder==true){           

         //if I start it on the reboot it will take wrong info and return wrong hours..

                      Intent inte = new Intent(c,AlarmService.class);
                         c.startService(inte);

                }
```

so it's calling a service that will recreate the alarms after that the device has rebooted 
and to create the alarms I need to get the location; It's working perfectly but sometimes the location is taken as 0.0 because the device doesn't have enough time to retrieve it;
I created a thread that launches the service after a certain time but that's not working as needed... so what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did:

OnBootReceiver I created an alarm that goes off after a minute and that calls the service when turned off; 
That way the location is taken in a correct way and don't have the

```
latitude=0.0
longitude=0.0
```

problem anymore...